# Can't open PID file /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid (yet?) after start: Too many levels of symbolic links MongoDB Centos 7

Tags: mongodb, centos7

I've installed mongodb on centos 7, but I can't start the service with systemctl.
Running `mongod` starts successfully.

I've followed all the instructions from here: https://mongoing.com/docs/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat.html

systemctl status mongod returns this:

```
* mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mongod.service.d
           `-override.conf
   Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Sun 2020-05-03 14:58:02 CEST; 4min 27s ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 528 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 525 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chmod 0755 /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 522 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chown mongod:mongod /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 519 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

May 03 14:56:32 zakazise systemd[1]: Starting MongoDB Database Server...
May 03 14:56:32 zakazise mongod[528]: about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
May 03 14:56:32 zakazise mongod[528]: forked process: 530
May 03 14:56:34 zakazise systemd[1]: Can't open PID file /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid (yet?) after start: Too many levels of symbolic links
May 03 14:58:02 zakazise systemd[1]: mongod.service start operation timed out. Terminating.
May 03 14:58:02 zakazise systemd[1]: Failed to start MongoDB Database Server.
May 03 14:58:02 zakazise systemd[1]: Unit mongod.service entered failed state.
May 03 14:58:02 zakazise systemd[1]: mongod.service failed.
```

There is a line in /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log , that I think might be important:

```
2020-05-03T14:58:02.210+0200 I  CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] got signal 15 (Terminated), will terminate after current cmd ends
```

/etc/mongod.conf:

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongo
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  wiredTiger:

# how the process runs
processManagement:
  fork: true  # fork and run in background
  pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid  # location of pidfile
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1  # Enter 0.0.0.0,:: to bind to all IPv4 and IPv6 addresses or, alternatively, use the net.bindIpAll setting.


#security:

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mongod.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=MongoDB Database Server
Documentation=https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
After=network.target

[Service]
User=mongod
Group=mongod
Environment="OPTIONS=-f /etc/mongod.conf"
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/mongod
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/mongodb
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chown mongod:mongod /var/run/mongodb
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chmod 0755 /var/run/mongodb
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod $OPTIONS
PermissionsStartOnly=true
PIDFile=/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid
Type=forking
# file size
LimitFSIZE=infinity
# cpu time
LimitCPU=infinity
# virtual memory size
LimitAS=infinity
# open files
LimitNOFILE=64000
# processes/threads
LimitNPROC=64000
# locked memory
LimitMEMLOCK=infinity
# total threads (user+kernel)
TasksMax=infinity
TasksAccounting=false
# Recommended limits for for mongod as specified in
# http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/ulimit/#recommended-settings

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**I didn't change anything in mongod.conf and mongod.service. This is a fully fresh install.**

**Steps I've tried:**

```
 touch /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid 
 chown mongod:mongod/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid
```

- I've checked every path with mongo in it, and they have the right
  privileges. (mongod:mongod)
- Checked that SELinux is disabled.
- Allowed 27017 in ufw.

**EDIT**

/var/run/mongodb has every rwx.

I'm logged in as root

Comment: Is the system fresh though? There is https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/3010 which suggests some kind of a systemd fail but I am not familiar with systemd internals to analyze that report.

Answer (score 0):

These two paths are different:

```
May 02 21:53:44 zakazise systemd[1]: Can't open PID file /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid (yet?) after start: Too many levels of symbolic links

pidFilePath: /var/run/mongo/mongod.pid  # location of pidfile
```

Comment: I've changed the path in mongod.service. Now I'm getting: `Can't open PID file /var/run/mongo/mongod.pid`
Even after I gave it 0777. `-rwxrwxrwx  1 mongod mongod     5 May  2 20:59 mongod.pid`

Comment: Its actually deleted every time I try to start mongod service...

Comment: Make sure the user that runs mongod process is allowed to write to /var/run/mongo/.

Comment: And create that directory if it doesn't exist.

Comment: `drwxrwxrwx  2 mongod mongod   40 May  2 23:57 mongo` still the same error

Comment: I'm also running it as root

Comment: Please update your question with the current state of things.

Comment: Take a look at it

Comment: You still have mismatched paths to the pid file.

Comment: I've updated the question. Changed PID path in mognod.conf to /var/run/mongodb, checked that every path has mongod:mongod permissions, still getting the same error..
If I execute the ExecStart command from mongod.service it runs successfully.

Comment: Since I can start it manually is there a way of running commands on startup?

Comment: You may consider something like https://github.com/shoken0x/mongodb-init-script instead of trying to do it all by hand.